The offset of the data in the column with the IMPORTAGE function
Well, I wrote my own code that works almost well. but unfortunately, the onEdit function does not take into account that the range is changed by the IMPORTAGE function. I had to add a checkbox, when changing which the function starts working. but I would like to automatically track changes, taking into account that the range is changed by the IMPORTAGE function.
The code simply aligns the range AL4:AL103 to the last filled cell in the range AK4:AK103
function onEdit(e) {
if (e && e.source) {
if (e.source.getSheetName() !== 'Calculation') return;
}
if (e) {
if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 37 && e.range.rowStart >= 1 && e.range.rowEnd <= 1) {
const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
const valuesA = sheet.getRange('AK4:AK102').getValues();
const valuesB = sheet.getRange('AL4:AL102').getValues();
// Здесь обрабатываем filteredValues
// Подсчёт значений во всём диапазоне
const allValuesA = valuesA.flat(); // Сглаживаем массив значений
const stringValuesA = allValuesA.filter(String); // Удаляем нестроковые значения
const countA = stringValuesA.length; // Считаем количество оставшихся значений
const allValuesB = valuesB.flat(); // Сглаживаем массив значений
const stringValuesB = allValuesB.filter(String); // Удаляем нестроковые значения
const countB = stringValuesB.length; // Считаем количество оставшихся значений
// Находим индекс последней строки с данными в диапазоне AK4:A103
const lastRowWithDataIndexA = valuesA.findLastIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
// Находим индекс последней строки с данными в диапазоне AL4:AL103
const lastRowWithDataIndexB = valuesB.findLastIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
const firstRowWithDataIndexB = valuesB.findIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
const firstDataB = lastRowWithDataIndexB-countB+1
const targetFirstDataPosB = lastRowWithDataIndexA-countB+1
const targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetFirstDataPosB, 38, 10, 1); // Целевой диапазон смещен на rowCount строк вниз
sheet.getRange(firstDataB, 38, valuesB.length, 1).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true}); // Копирование содержимого столбца B в целевой диапазон
const delData = targetFirstDataPosB-4
if (targetFirstDataPosB >= 4) {
sheet.getRange(4, 38, delData, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});
}   
}
}
}

I wanted my code to track changes in AK4:AK103 cells. which in turn change the IMPORTAGE functions. the onEdit function did not help me in this, I had to add a checkbox to cell AK1. when changing which, the function started working.
can you tell me how best to implement this?
can the onChange or onSelectionChange functions help me with this? I couldn't get them to work in my code.

Please format the code properly. Use indents to make it easier to identify each block. You can use the command Format Document from the Apps Script Editor to add the indents automaticaly. Just right click on a code line, the select the corresponding command in contextual menu.

While here onChange and onSelectionChange are mentioned, the answer is the same given for the onEdit trigger, a formula result change doesn't activate triggers. You should set the trigger to be activated by the precedent parameter source, in this case, the source spreadsheet.
